# Delete a running Service from a different activity Android

Tags: android, service, fragment

I start a service to see the accelerometer data on my main activity, and I have a button on a fragment and I want to finish my service with that button but I keep getting this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'boolean android.content.Context.stopService(android.content.Intent)'
> on a null object reference

This is my mainactivity where I create the service

```
public class FragmentManager extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onPressStartService(Background_accelerometer.TAG);
    }

    public void onPressStartService(final String tag){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"start");
        intent = new Intent(FragmentManager.this, Background_accelerometer.class);
        intent.addCategory(tag);
        startService(intent);

    }
    public void onPressStopService(final String tag){
        intent = new Intent(FragmentManager.this, Background_accelerometer.class);
        intent.addCategory(tag);
        stopService(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my service

```
public class Background_accelerometer extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
    public static final String TAG = "MyServiceTag";
    public Background_accelerometer() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Service Started","Service Started");
        mInitialized = false;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

and this my fragment with the button

```
public class FragmentDeveloper_2  extends Fragment {

    FragmentManager FM = new FragmentManager();
    Button stopBtn;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_developer, container, false);
        stopBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FM.onPressStopService(Background_accelerometer.TAG);

            }
        });


        return view;

    }
```

How can I put a tag on my service to be able to close it or call it back from other activities?

Comment: Have you included your service in your manifest?

Comment: Yes!
        <service
            android:name=".Background_accelerometer"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problems with this line:

```
FragmentManager FM = new FragmentManager();
```

Your class name causes confusion, it's not a [FragementManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager) but an [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity). Activities cannot be instantiated by you, like this.

What you need make the host Activity of your fragment to execute `onPressStopService()` is to [let it know through a ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#viewmodel). You could also do it through registering a callback but now ViewModel is the documented method.

Otherwise you could also take a shortcut and run directly:

```
stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Activity a = requireActivity()
                 Intent intent = new Intent(a, Background_accelerometer.class);
                 intent.addCategory(tag);
                 a.stopService(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Now I understood, thank you very much! =)